# Get Device Brightness when building ThemeData, outside of Material App with MediaQuery

Tags: flutter

I want to display dark or light mode based on the settings of the device.

I need to get the brightness of the device when building my `ThemeData`, something like this:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final materialLightTheme = ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor0(Brightness.light),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: MyColors.backgroundColor1(Brightness.light)
      ),
    );


    final materialDarkTheme = ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor0(Brightness.dark),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: MyColors.backgroundColor1(Brightness.dark)
      ),
    );


    Brightness brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;

    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: brightness == Brightness.light
        ? ThemeMode.light
        : ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: materialLightTheme,
      darkTheme: materialDarkTheme,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );

  }
}
```

But it seems, MediaQuery is not available in the build Method outside of an Material App. I get the Error

> MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a
>   MediaQuery.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for your use case, if you just want to apply dark and light theme based on system's dark mode, then it is automatically handled by the Flutter, just by providing the `darkTheme` property in your `MaterialApp` widget, whenever the system's dark mode is activated, the theme supplied in the `darkTheme` parameter will automatically activate.

However if you do want to access MediaQuery before you apply themes and other stuff to your app via `MaterialApp`, from what I know you need either `MaterialApp` or `WidgetsApp` before in the widget tree in order to get the `MediaQuery.of(context)`. However, we can workaround that by using, two `MaterialApp` widgets one for just getting the MediaQuery in the second you apply the theming and all other stuff as below

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final materialLightTheme = ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor0(Brightness.light),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: MyColors.backgroundColor1(Brightness.light)
      ),
    );


    final materialDarkTheme = ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor0(Brightness.dark),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: MyColors.backgroundColor1(Brightness.dark)
      ),
    );


    Brightness brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;

    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: brightness == Brightness.light
        ? ThemeMode.light
        : ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: materialLightTheme,
      darkTheme: materialDarkTheme,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The CupertinoApp does not have an `darkTheme` parameter, which I want to use. However using a MaterialWidget before the CupertinoWidget works just fine.

Comment: @Jonas Any idea upon detecting Dark mode in CupertinoWidget?